# jquery $.ajax, success: textStatus silently ignored....firebug says nothing

Tags: jquery

i dont know what is happening here.

ajax is posted successfully. firebug doesn't complain.

however, success: function(){alert("complete");} never fires. its almost as if it is ignored.

success: alert("coomplete"); will of course fire everytime this ajax request runs.

please help!

Comment: `success: alert("coomplete");` always fires because it is evaluating the alert immediately, but not after the AJAX request is completed.  Please provide the entire AJAX call so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with your dataType value.  I just ran into this problem and solved it by removing the dataType line since I wasn't returning anything.  After that it ran just fine.  Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if call is returning with any error ?

```
error: function(){
     $("#your_div_id").empty().append("Error");
}
```